# Gradle getting newest version for some libraries

Tags: java, spring, gradle

There is not any place in my project where I mentioned that I want to use any Spring library version 4.3.8.RELEASE. However, when doing an "assemble", Gradle picks up newest version for couple of dependencies. When I do a "gradle dependencies", I see:

```
+--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
 |    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.RELEASE
 |    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
 |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.6.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE
 |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE
 |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
 |    |    |    |    |         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
 |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
 |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.6.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
 |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.6.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE
 |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
```

Why the hell is Gradle doing something like : aop:3.2.6.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE

Any other commands to track where a dependency come from?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: It did. It's of course kind of questions where none can provide an answer which 100% match, as part of the problem is also our internal organisation ... but yep, it helped. Sory I forgot to come back on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those might be transitive dependencies coming from a different library.

Use `dependencyInsight` to track what comes from where.

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --configuration <configuration> --dependency <dependency>
```

`<dependency>` - name of the dependency

`<configuration>` - compile, runtime etc.

You can also use dependencies and pipe it to the file and search for it manually.

```
gradle dependencies >deps.txt
```

---

Additional source [gradle getting more dependency](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/gradle-goodness-getting-more-dependency.html)